# Exit out of condition statement after condition was met in Racket

Tags: racket

I have a condition statement such as:

```
(cond 

     [ (and (null? E1) (not (null? E2))) #f]

     [ (and (not (null? E1)) (null? E2)) #f]

     [ (or (= (length E1) 1) (= (length E2) 1))

          (cond 
            [ (equal? E1 E2) #t]
            [ (equal? (reverse E1) E2) #t]
            [ else #f break]
            )]

    [ .... conditions continue
```

Is there a way of exiting out of the cond statement, after either the #f or #t is reached, and not continuing to the bottom, checking all the rest of the conditions? Just like in python, there is 'break' to get out of loops.

Comment: To clarify, I only need it to break if the condition that results in either the #t or #f is met. If it does not, I would still like the code to continue executing

Comment: no, it is still unclear what you ask for. `else` means `#t` always, that's what it's for, to begin with. If the control reaches the line `[ else #f break]`, do you want it to continue on to the lower clauses and try more conditions? Yes or No, please?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... If I understand you correctly, then the behavior you want is the behavior that's built in. Here's an example:

```
#lang racket

(define (my-fun E1 E2)
  (cond 
    [(and (null? E1) (not (null? E2))) #f]

    [(and (not (null? E1)) (null? E2)) #f]

    [(or (= (length E1) 1) (= (length E2) 1)) 
     (cond 
       [(equal? E1 E2) #t]
       [(equal? (reverse E1) E2) #t]
       [else #f])] ;; <-- the break was here.
    [(dont-run-this-check) #t]
    [(dont-run-this-check-either) #f]
    [(really-really-dont-run-this-check) #t]))

(my-fun '(a b c) '(d))

(define (dont-run-this-check) (error))
(define (dont-run-this-check-either) (error))
(define (really-really-dont-run-this-check) (error))
```

This evaluates to `#f`

In this example, the code "breaks" on the line labeled "the break was here", and never evaluates any of the following tests (if it did, you'd see an error). That's because once the outer 'cond' has chosen a clause, none of the rest of them will be evaluated.

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: To clarify a little, in `cond`, the first *condition* that evaluates to `#t` will prevent all other conditions from being evaluated, so if `(or (= (length E1) 1) (= (length E2) 1))` evaluates to `#t`, the following conditions in the *same* `cond` will not be evaluated. The inner `cond` is a part of the *body* of the `(or ....` condition. See the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29).

Answer (score 0):

In a `cond`

```
(cond 
   (predicate1 consequent1)
   (predicate2 consequent2)
   (else alternative))
```

It is the same as:

```
(if predicate1
    consequent1
    (if predicate2
        consequent2
        alternative))
```

Thus if predicate1 matches the expression consequent1 will be the evaluateion of the whole `cond` form.

If you nest `cond` the evaluation of the whole `cond` will be the evaluation of the inner when the predicate for the nested cond matches.

One other difference between `if` is that `cond` can have more than one consequent/alternative expression since it has explicit begin.. Thus you code where you have `

```
(cond ...
      [else #f break])
```

Here if the other predicates don't match it will always match `else`. Then if will first evaluate #f (which is redundant since it doesn't do any side effects) before it evaluates `break` and it's value will be the result.